# Android: override Resource in layout

Tags: java, android, resources, warnings

Sometimes I see a warning like this:

[image]

What happen if I override or not the layout Resource?

Comment: [Don't post images of error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3750257)

Answer (score 2):

If you override the layout resource, a new copy of it is created with configuration qualifiers. In this case, `layout-v26`. This version of the resource is used on API level 26 and above while the qualifier-free version in `layout` is the default.

For issues like this you probably don't want to do that as then you have one more version of the layout to maintain.

Unknown XML attributes are ignored at runtime, so the problem is only that the attribute does nothing on pre-v26 runtimes. If that's fine, then you can just ignore the warning with `tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"`.

Comment: Thank you so much